# How do I find the password to a hard drive partition?

Tags: partitioning, password, cryptsetup

I am running Lubuntu 13.04 and I have a problem with a partition on my external drive. Basically, I either do not remember the password or some sort of error is not allowing my access the partition.

My questions are actually two:

1. How can I find the password to a drive partition if I forgot it?
2. Please refer to the image attached, I am getting that error when I try and use the password, and I am wondering whether I actually forgot the password or there is some other problem.

Thanks beforehand for any assistance given.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your issue is about a forgotten or wrong password. It seems that your installation does not have `cryptsetup` installed. Install it: [cryptsetup [image: Install cryptsetup]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cryptsetup) and try again.

> How can I find the password to a drive partition if I forgot it?

Well, the whole purpose of the hard drive encryption is to keep the data safe for ones not having the password. Storing the password on the system would basically undermine the whole purpose of running encryption in the first place. Passwords are for you to remember, not to store anywhere!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cannot try out your suggestion as I went around the problem by using my Ubuntu 12.10 distribution, and the password worked, so it is probable that cryptsetup was not installed.

Comment: @Ederico Interesting... the answer was here 3 minutes (!) after you posted your question and you already worked around it? Maybe you should give it a bit more time before you start reinstalling. ;)

Comment: I did not reinstall anything, I have a system running Lubuntu and Ubuntu, it was there already. :-) I just did not notice your answer before I tried accessing the password protected partition on Ubuntu, rather than Lubuntu.